# Is there a way to delete an object from database in html document? (django)

Tags: javascript, django, sqlite, django-models

view.html

```
<th><button id={{p.id}} onclick="Delete(this.id)" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</button></th>
  <script>
    function Delete(row_id){
      document.getElementById(row_id).remove();
      {{dogss.objects.filter(id=1)}.delete()}} //I wanted this to happen, but it's not working
    }
  </script>
</tr>
```

view.py

```
def view(response):
return render(response, "main/view.html", {"dogs": Dog.objects.filter(user=response.user), "dogss": Dog})
```

I know that I can make that button interact with .py file and from there it will probably work. But I'm curious why this isn't working?

Comment: Because templates are rendered at server side. The client never receives any `{% for ... %}` template tags, or template filters, or `{{ some_variable }}`. The render engine translates the template tags/filters according to their implementation to HTML. So the JavaScript will never contain something to remove an item at the server side. You can make a view that removes an object, for example with a POST request that you then make on the webpage through an AJAX call.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any examples maybe for ajax call? I dont't know what that is...

Comment: Here's an example AJAX request made with Django: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html